# How to check if PGSQL server is still alive with DBD::PG?

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbd-pg

I am desperately trying to find an easy way to regulary check if a PGSQL server is still alive from within a perl script. I intended to use `pg_ping` for this, but in my tests pg_ping always returns 1, independently of the DB server status.

Here's the code I tried it with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBD::Pg;

my $dbh=DBI->connect("DBI:Pg:dbname=healthcheck;host=vm0484","healthcheck","areyoustillthere");
for (my $i=1;$i<100;$i++) {
print "$i. pg_ping: ".$dbh->pg_ping."\n";
sleep(1);
}
```

I then used `kill -9` in another window to manually terminate the PGSQL-server, but the result was still `1`. Did I do something wrong?

If not, how do I best check, if the DB server is still alive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the manual: _Important: It is best not to use SIGKILL to shut down the server. Doing so will prevent the server from releasing shared memory and semaphores, which might then have to be done manually before a new server can be started. Furthermore, SIGKILL kills the postgres process without letting it relay the signal to its subprocesses, so it will be necessary to kill the individual subprocesses by hand as well._

Comment: Well, that's what I wanted. A way to test if the script realizes, that the server/the VM crashed. Crashes normally don't SIGINT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually perform query like

```
select 1 as is_alive
```

as [`ping()`](http://search.cpan.org/~rudy/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm#ping) also claim to do something similar,

> The ping method issues an empty query and checks the result status.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, doesn't seem to work. I can even perform real queries when the PGSQL-server has been killed, which seems pretty fishy. I think I'm making a terrible stupid erro somewhere.

Comment: @m3adow are you sure that server is really dead? Perform second `kill` on PID which in turn should complain only if server is down.

Comment: Oh man, thanks a lot. This was REALLY a Layer 8 problem. I only partially killed PGSQL. Everything works fine and I am dumb.